# Microsoft Graph - trying to get email list gives 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying get emails from my Office365 mailbox, using the [MS Graph Docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages) as reference - using [Access without user flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). I am able to get the bearer token ok. The JWT has the roles array containing:

```
roles: [  "Mail.ReadWrite", "Mail.Read" ]
```

Here's the code I am using. It's getting the 400 on the "last line.

```
        var web = new WebClient();
        web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

        var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        reqparm.Add("client_id", cliID);
        reqparm.Add("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");            
        reqparm.Add("client_secret", secret);
        reqparm.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

        var responsebytes = web.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responsebody);

        web = new WebClient();
        web.Headers.Add( HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + data.access_token);            
        var url2 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages";
        var messages = web.DownloadString(url2);
```

To be sure that it wasn't the WebClient doing something other than GET I also tried a HttpWebRequest with method = "GET", and the same result.

Here's the POCO:

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `/me` when authenticating without a User. This is because there isn't a User in context for Graph to translate `/me` into.

For this scenario, you'll need to specify which `user` resource you want to list messages for:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/messages
```

Comment: @MarcLeFleur - I thought that's what the token was for, to identify "me", as I used the tenant ID when requesting the token. Regardless, since posting this (and subsequently giving up) I tried that URL, but with the username from the email address, and got a 404. EX:  Joe@Domain.com --- I would have tried: /users/joe/messages.   I didn't setup the account in Office365 - what should info should I ask my admin for? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/messages`

As @MarcLeFleur mentioned it was the user prinicpal; so I tried the username in the email and that didn't work. I used the **full email address** for the principal and viola!